# LogLinearPlot analog for Plot3D?

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to make 3D plot in logarithmic coordinates? I need analog LogLinearPlot to plot 3D figure in logarithmic x, or y, or both coordinates.

Comment: You can evaluate `?*Log*` to search for such a function.  Since there doesn't seem to be one, you will need to transform the plotted function accordingly (`f[Exp[x], Exp[y]]`) and use custom `Tick` marks for correct labelling.

Comment: Could you please show a simple example with log tick in x axes?